# Python For loops Creating Diffrent Lists

Tags: python

I have an idea but don't know how to execute it.

i have a variable value EG: 5
now i want my python program to create 5 different list all with differnt names
EG: list1 = []
list2 = []
...

Comment: What do you need this for? IMO it would be a lot simpler to have a list of lists. Alternatively a dict with your "variable names" as key can also work.

Comment: I think you need to tell us why you are trying to do this. Because first up, it seems like something that shouldn't really be done. Second to that though, you could use a dictionary

Comment: @jabobGoodall, do not listen to people that says "I think you need to tell us why you are trying to do this.".  They simply lack imagination.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible. When you say `list1`, you mean that `list1` is an identifier for a variable which is a list. I don't think it is possible that the program creates identifiers within itself (or at least I don't know how).

Of course, you can write a Python program which *writes another Python program* where there are variables with these identifiers, then get creative with it:

```py
VAL = 5 # can change this
f = open("lists.py", "w")
for i in range(1, VAL + 1):
    f.write("list" + str(i) + " = []\n")
f.close()
```

Output (lists.py):

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
list4 = []
list5 = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Morning Jacob,

I have a little bit of difficulties reading your question.  But let me try to answer your question.

### Direct answer

There are no simple way to generate python variables.  The only way I know is to generate the code as str and then execute it.

```
def generate_code(n):
    ret = ""
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        var_name = "lst_" + str(i)
        ret += var_name + " = []\n"
    return ret

code = generate_code(5)
print(code)
exec(code)
```

where the printed code will be

```
lst_1 = []
lst_2 = []
lst_3 = []
lst_4 = []
lst_5 = []
```

### The idiomatic solution

The idiomatic solution would be to create a list of list.  Something like bellow.

```
lsts = [[] for i in range(5)]
```

then, you could access your sub lists using indexes in a very similar fashion then with the variables you asked for.  `lsts[0]` would be equivalent of the above `lst_1`, `lsts[1]` would be equivalent of the above `lst_2`, `lsts[2]` would be equivalent of the above `lst_3`, ...